# Using a stored procedure inside of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that queries some results. I have another stored procedure that needs to return the results of the first stored procedure and the results of a query to a table. Currently, the body of this stored procedure looks something like this:

```
EXEC myFirstStoredProc @param1

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

When I execute mySecondStoredProc, the results of MyTable appear. However, the results of the EXEC statement do not appear. How do I get the results of the nested sproc call to appear?

Thank you!

Comment: You should get 2 separate result sets assuming the stored proc returns any results. How are you testing this? Also is the idea that they should be `UNION`-ed together into one result set?

Comment: It is a SQL Server 2008 instance. There is no union necessary.

Comment: Are you viewing this in management studio or something else? (that doesn't understand/support multiple result sets)

Comment: I am viewing it in SQL Server Management Studio. But I've done multiple result sets in the past. In fact, I just added a second query just to test it and it worked fine. Its just the stored procedure call that's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server what you've described should work.

Here's a sample that you can use to see it in action

```
CREATE PROC testProc
AS 
BEGIN
    exec sp_helpdb
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables
END
```

Comment: @Phone Developer you should execute it as `exec testProc`

Comment: I fixed it. There was some weird parsing error going on. My fault. I've marked this one as the answer as its the best answer.